# Getting errors because compiler confuses static enum class between C++11 and Managed C++

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, managed-c++, enum-class

I have recently migrated a Managed C++ project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013.

Inside the definition of a class, I have:

```
static enum class ItemType
{
    SHOP=IDS_SHOP,
    PAGE=IDS_PAGE,
    PHOTO=IDS_PHOTO
};


static bool EnumTryParse(CString sItemType, ItemType& refItemType)
{       
    System::String^ sType = gcnew System::String(sItemType);
    return System::Enum::TryParse(sType, refItemType);
}
```

Trying to compile it is giving me errors. The reason seems to be that 2013 version uses C++11 behind the scenes and it confuses the Managed C++ enum class with the C++11 enum class.

What is the proper way to adapt my code to the new version?

Comment: Yes, C++11 issue.  Use an access specifier to convince the compiler you meant to declare a managed enum, either private or public.  Not valid in C++11.  So probably ought to be `private enum class ItemType` here.